# How to convert an SVG image using JavaScript into SVG code to get the polygon or path?

Tags: javascript, svg, polygon

I'm interested in knowing whether it is possible to select an SVG file, let's say, example.svg in your html file using JavaScript/jQuery and get the polygon/polypath/path as a string for further manipulations **without saving the image to desktop and using InkScape/Adobe Illustrator or any other vector processing program to extract the code manually**.

Here's what I'm aiming for:

*BEFORE*

```
<img src="example.svg" />
```

*AFTER*

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,180 190,....." style="......"/>
</svg>
```

and the code I'm hoping to work with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // convert the svg into polygon, for instance
    function convertSVG(svg){
        ...
    }

    convertSVG(/* get that SVG in img tags */);

})
```

Comment: Not if you've loaded it as an image, but it would be possible if it was an object or embed or iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, it looks like you can just do something like

```
$.get("/path/to/file.svg", function(data) {
    var svg_data = data.childNodes;
});
```

Then, `svg_data`, will hold the tags of the SVG data, in a DOM node format, so you could do things like:

```
$("#my_holder").html(svg_data);
```

And then `#my_holder` will have the image in it.